# Java private method signature clarity and better practice

Tags: java, code-readability

I received the code review comment for below code snippet -

```
public void doWork(String a, Integer b) {
    ..
    ..
    SomeService service = getService();
    for (Integer i : numbers) {
      doMoreWork(a, b, service);
    }
}
private void doMoreWork(String a, Integer b, SomeService service) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    service.doingMoreWork(a, b);
}
```

review suggestion -

1. `SomeService service = getService();` should be called within `doMoreWork` for signature clarity. so signature becomes `doMoreWork(a, b)` which is more clear to understand.

My question -

Since `doMoreWork()` is happening in a loop, I am passing a service object to it.  doMoreWork() is just a private logical unit within a code, it should be fine to carry "service" as method argument. This method is never going to be public. What is the guideline in this case? How the clarity or readability is affected here?

(NOTE :

1. There is not much performance overhead to `getService()` call so performance is not a criteria for me here.
2. Service injection is not an option here. It needs to be fetched the way shown in the sample.
3. doMoreWork() is not just about calling service.doingMoreWork(). It has some pre-steps to follow.

)

Comment: If this is the real code, I would inline "doMoreWork", I don't see why you need a method here (it's 1 LoC)

Comment: I have edited the sample code now. doMoreWork() is doing some more work!

Comment: I have asked the question to know the best practice or even fact behind this suggestion. This is something I could not find out from books so I posted it here. I am not sure if it is really a candidate for "hold". Even responses are reasonable and not just opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

If you refactor `doMoreWork()` to the following:

```
private void doMoreWork(String a, Integer b) {
    SomeService service = getService();
    service.doingMoreWork(a, b);
}
```

then you are making `doMoreWork()` dependent on `getService()` for its functionality.  If you ever want to use a different method to obtain a `SomeService` object you will have to refactor this code.  So you might want to stick with the original implementation for this reason.

If you are using a framework like Spring, you could have the `SomeService` injected into your class like this:

```
@Autowired
private SomeService service;

// use the injected service here
private void doMoreWork(String a, Integer b) {
    service.doingMoreWork(a, b);
}
```

Comment: +1 This to me is the cleanest solution - nominal code and greatest flexibility.  The doMoreWork method shouldn't care about the service used to do more work.  You can swap out the service in a modular fashion with DI.

Answer (score 0):

As suggestion is right you need `Service` object only in the `doMoreWork` method. So it is good to get the `Service` object only in the `doMoreWork` method perform your operations.

If more statements are added after the `loop`, then `Service` object will last for long until its scope is there (until closing `}` is not encountered), it will not be garbage collected therefore you should call `getService()` in `doMoreWork` and pass 2 parameters in `doMoreWork(a,b)`. It will be more easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

From a code clarity perspective, `doMoreWork` is an instance method in a class which knows its service (i.e., it has a `getService()` method). Putting the `Service` in the signature makes the reader wonder what `Service` this method is referring to, so it's somewhat confusing. Such a signature would make perfect sense, though, in a class which has multiple services and has to do the same type of work on several of them.

Comment: yes this could be one of the guideline to decide relevance of input argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, it does one no good to have that variable declared except within the `doMoreWork` method.  Here's why:

- No (apparent) mutations are being done to it inside of `doWork`
- `getService()` appears to always return the same instance of `SomeService`

Depending on if `getService` is just a getter to a field, then it might be better to use the field directly instead of going through the method.  But, you really don't need to pass this value in to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Passing Service as a parameter would have made sense, if `getService()` returned a new instance every time but then its name should have been `createNewService()` instead.

In current scenario it seems that `getService()` is always returning the same instance, so passing Service as a parameter does not make any difference but to confuse the reader.

Further adding, `getService()` is defined in the same class and `doMoreWork()` is a private method, so it would always refer to the same service probably than why add an extra step to pass `Service` every time!

Another thing, if all `doMoreWork()` does is to call `service.doingMoreWork(a, b);` nothing else than it would be better to just delete this method and call it directly in the loop like this:

```
public void doWork(String a, Integer b) {
    ..
    ..
    for (Integer i : numbers) {
        getService().doingMoreWork(a, b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the code review, `getService()` should be in `doMoreWork()`.

Moreover, I suggest to **make the service as your dependency of your class**, that is, service can be a field of your class. Some DI framework can inject the service for you, such as *Spring framework*.

If so, `this.service` can be referenced in each method of your class.

Comment: yeah we did consider service injection. But in my case we can not do it. It has to be fetched the way I have done.

Answer (score 0):

#### It does not matter because:

`doMoreWork()` is marked `private` it is a hidden detail of the class.
Since it is not `public` it is not part of the `public` API or Contract, it is an implementation detail that can change.

So it really does not matter what the signature is the reason given in your question is just personal preference.

You would never create a new JDBC connection inside a loop it would be extremely inefficient, even with a good connection pool it would be the wrong thing to do.

#### All that said I would do it this way.

The `private` method is not needed and just adds confusion and opinion.

```
public void doWork(@Nonnull final String s, @Nonnull final Integer i) 
{
    final SomeService service = getService();
    for (final Integer n : numbers) 
    {
      service.doingMoreWork(s, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: doMoreWork() has been extracted out as it has logical steps related to each other. It is not straight call to service.doMoreWork(). Let me edit the sample code.